# AJAX request keeps caching, how do I prevent it?

Tags: ajax, superagent

Using super agent, my get request keeps caching is there a way to stop this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try [superagent-no-cache](https://github.com/johntron/superagent-no-cache).

Description from their docs:

> Plugin for visionmedia/superagent that adds headers to all requests that prevents caching

Demo from their docs:

```
var request = require('superagent')
var noCache = require('superagent-no-cache')

request.get('/url')
    .use(noCache)
    .end(function _requestCallback() {
        // do something
    });
```